# Using headers with the Robot Framework requests library's 'Get Request' Keyword

Tags: robotframework

I want to test API using Requests Library.

My Code is as follows:

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation     Read API Testcase
Library           RequestsLibrary

*** Variables ***
${headers}        {'content-type': 'application/json', 'authorizationFlag':'N'}

*** Test Cases ***
Read API
    Create Session    CLM    http://172.20.33.224:8080/clm-reg/rest/dataservice/1/CLM/1
    ${resp}    Get Request    CLM    /RegistrationRequestDetails/json/583d8b14498e021b2f93a773    headers = ${headers} 
    Log to console    ${resp}
```

I am getting the error :

```
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'items'
```

I found the problem with the Headers i am passing.

when i searched over the internet, i got that the way i am passing the header values is correct.

Please any one help me on this.

Thanks
Sarada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `${headers}` var is just a string, not a dictionary.
JSON is tricky that way. You have several options to create a dictionary in RF.

- RF's `Create Dictionary` keyword
- Python's `json.loads(str)` as a lib call
- RF's `Evaluate` keyword...

Answer (score 2):

I've changed your headers line to what should work.  Let us know if you've any success or what other problems you get tripped up on.

```
*** Variables ***
${headers}       Create Dictionary    Content-Type    application/json    authorisationFlag    N
```

Comment: Thanks Shicky, it worked but with little change. instead of under variables, i created in the script as below: 

    `*** Test Cases ***   
    Read API  
        Create Session    CLM    http://172.20.33.224:8080/clm-reg/rest/dataservice/1/CLM/1  
        &{headers}    Create Dictionary    Content-Type=application/json    authorizationFlag=N  
         ${resp}    Get Request    CLM    /RegistrationRequestDetails/json/583d8b14498e021b2f93a773    headers=${headers}  
        Log to console    ${resp}`

Comment: That works, but I prefer specifying a `Suite Setup` keyword, in which you can transform JSON to dict using `Evaluate` (Pythonic.) Remember to `Set Suite Variable` on any var you want visible.

Comment: I understand the logic MarkHu, in some test suites we're sending different types of requests and using different headers so prefer to keep it within the test cases.  Depends on the use case I guess!

Comment: @MarkHu could you please provide an example on how to assign a loaded json to a variable? Cannot get my head around this. Thx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the built-in variable dictionary type like this:

```
    Set Test Variable    &{HEADERS}       Content-Type=application/json    authorisationFlag=N    Accept=*/*    Cache-Control=no-cache
```

Then call it as a variable which spread as a dict on your headers variable:

```
    ${resp}    Post Request   api-encoder    /api-token-auth/    data=${DATA}    headers=${HEADERS}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried several methods on Robot Framework 5.0.1 (Python 3.11.3 on darwin), below code works:

```
      ${HEADERS}    Create Dictionary
      Set To Dictionary     ${HEADERS}    Content-Type=application/json        accept=*/*
```